# How to parse a JSON in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: json, ruby, parsing, speech-to-text

I am writing an automation script that uses IBM Watson Speech to Text API. Check the code below (I used the IBM's Speech to Text documentation).

```
require "ibm_watson/authenticators"
require "ibm_watson/speech_to_text_v1"
include IBMWatson

authenticator = Authenticators::IamAuthenticator.new(
  apikey: "{apikey}"
)
speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1.new(
  authenticator: authenticator
)
speech_to_text.service_url = "{url}"

speech_to_text.configure_http_client(disable_ssl_verification: true)

File.open("audio-file.flac") do |audio_file|
  speech_recognition_results = speech_to_text.recognize(
    audio: audio_file,
    content_type: "audio/flac",
    word_alternatives_threshold: 0.9
  )
  transcript_json = JSON.pretty_generate(speech_recognition_results.result)
  puts transcript_json
end
```

Every time I run the command `ruby test.rb` on my terminal, it gives me the transcription result in JSON.

```
LaboteamnoMacBook-puro:GoogleDriveApiTest laboteam$ ruby test.rb
{
  "result_index": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "final": true,
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "several tornadoes touched down as a line of severe thunderstorms swept through Colorado on Sunday ",
          "confidence": 0.94
        }
      ],
....
}
```

I'd like to `parse` it but I don't know how because there is a lot of sub key-value pairs. I only want to get the value of the `transcript` key inside the `alternatives` key. Hope to get some response about how to parse this JSON.

Comment: Try `puts transcript_json["results"]["alternatives"].first["transcript"]` :)

Answer (score 0):

```rb
require 'json'

json = '{"key":"value"}'

res = JSON.parse(json)

puts res["key"]
```